# How to set some item unclickable in GridView

Tags: android, listview, gridview

For example, I need to judge the contents of the item in the Item can be clicked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYwNs.png)
As shown in the picture, I need to get the gray Item cannot be clicked.

Here is my adapter

```
 public class RoomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Context mContext;
        private List<Room> mDatas;


        public RoomAdapter(Context context, List<Room> mDatas) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mDatas = mDatas;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mDatas.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mDatas.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Room room = mDatas.get(position);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            View view;
            if (convertView == null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.roomstate_item, null);
                viewHolder.tv_roomstate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_roomstate);
                viewHolder.tv_roomnumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_roomnumber);
                viewHolder.tv_roomtype = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_roomtype);
                viewHolder.tv_roomprice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_roomprice);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            }else{
                view = convertView;
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
    //        String nu = room.getRoom_number();
            viewHolder.tv_roomstate.setText(room.getRoom_status());
            viewHolder.tv_roomnumber.setText(room.getRoom_number());
            viewHolder.tv_roomtype.setText(room.getRoomType().getRoom_type_name());
            viewHolder.tv_roomprice.setText(room.getRoomType().getRoom_type_price());

            if (room.getRoom_status().equals("0") &&room.getRoomType().getRoom_type_name().equals("0")) {
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.single);
               view.setClickable(false);
            } else if (room.getRoom_status().equals("1") && room.getRoomType().getRoom_type_name().equals("0")) {
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.single_b);
            } else if (room.getRoom_status().equals("1") && room.getRoomType().getRoom_type_name().equals("1")) {
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.double_b);
            } else if(room.getRoom_status().equals("0") && room.getRoomType().getRoom_type_name().equals("1")){
                view.setClickable(false);
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.doubleg);
            }

            return view;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView tv_roomnumber;
            TextView tv_roomstate;
            TextView tv_roomtype;
            TextView tv_roomprice;
        }
    }
```

Here is my Activity

```
public class RoomList extends Activity {
    private ImageView iv_back;
    private TextView tv_hotelname;

    private GridView griv_hotel;

    private RoomAdapter adapter;
    private String hotelname;
    private String url
            = "http://jm/user/room/selectRoomByHotelName?hotel_name=";

    private List<Room> mRoom;
    private RoomType mRoomType;
    private boolean isfinish = false;//判断请求是否完成
    private String hotel_address;
    private String hotel_id;
    private Bundle mBundle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_room_list);
        init();
        sendRequestWithOkHttp();
        boolean is = true;
        while (is) {
            if (isfinish) {
                adapter = new RoomAdapter(this, mRoom);
                griv_hotel.setAdapter(adapter);
                griv_hotel.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        TextView tv_roomnumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_roomnumber);
                        TextView tv_roomstate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_roomstate);
                        TextView tv_roomprice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_roomprice);
                        TextView tv_roomtype = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_roomtype);

                        String roomnumber = tv_roomnumber.getText().toString();
                        String roomstate = tv_roomstate.getText().toString();
                        String roomtype = tv_roomtype.getText().toString();
                        String roomprice = tv_roomprice.getText().toString();

                        Log.e("房间类型",roomtype);

//                        if (roomstate.equals("0") && roomtype.equals("0")) {
//                            view.setClickable(false);
//                        } else if (roomstate.equals("1") && roomtype.equals("0")) {
//                           view.setClickable(true);
//                        } else if (roomstate.equals("1") && roomtype.equals("1")) {
//                            view.setClickable(true);
//                        } else {
//                            view.setClickable(false);
//                        }

                        mBundle.putString("roomnumber", roomnumber);
                        mBundle.putString("roomstate", roomstate);
                        mBundle.putString("roomtype", roomtype);
                        mBundle.putString("roomprice", roomprice);
                        mBundle.putString("hoteladdress", hotel_address);
                        mBundle.putString("hotelid", hotel_id);


                        Intent intent = new Intent(RoomList.this, BookRoomDetail.class);
                        intent.putExtras(mBundle);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                is = false;
            }
        }


    }

    private void init() {
        initView();
        initEvents();
    }

    private void initEvents() {
        iv_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initView() {
        iv_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_back);
        tv_hotelname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_hotelname);
        mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        hotelname = mBundle.getString("hotelname");

        tv_hotelname.setText(hotelname);
        griv_hotel = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.griv_hotel);


    }

    private void sendRequestWithOkHttp() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN
                        = MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown; charset=utf-8");
                try {
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    String postBody = hotelname;
                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(url + hotelname)
                            .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN, postBody))
                            .build();
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    String responseData = response.body().string();
                    try {
                        parseJSON(responseData);
                        isfinish = true;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void parseJSON(String responseData) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray JSONArray = new JSONArray(responseData);
        mRoom = new ArrayList<Room>();
        for (int i = 0; i < JSONArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject JSON = JSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String room_number = JSON.getString("room_number");
                String room_status = JSON.getString("room_status");
                JSONObject jsonObject = JSON.getJSONObject("roomType");
                String room_type_name = jsonObject.getString("room_type_name");
                String room_type_price = jsonObject.getString("room_type_price");
                JSONObject jsonObj = JSON.getJSONObject("hotel");
                hotel_id = String.valueOf(jsonObj.getInt("hotel_id"));
                hotel_address = jsonObj.getString("hotel_location");
                mRoomType = new RoomType(null, room_type_name, room_type_price, null, null);

                mRoom.add(new Room(null, room_number, room_status, null, null, mRoomType));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I set view.setClickable (false)in my Adapter, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is to write a Boolean value, and let it based on a Boolean value to determine whether to jump.

```
private boolean checkedIntent = false;


if (roomstate.equals("0") && roomtype.equals("0")) {
                        checkedIntent = false;
                    } else if (roomstate.equals("1") && roomtype.equals("0")) {
                        checkedIntent = true;
                    } else if (roomstate.equals("1") && roomtype.equals("1")) {
                        checkedIntent = true;
                    } else if (roomstate.equals("0") && roomtype.equals("1")) {
                        checkedIntent = false;
                    }

if (checkedIntent == true) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RoomList.this, BookRoomDetail.class);
                            intent.putExtras(mBundle);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
item.setEnabled(false);
```

when u need to make it clickable call

```
item.setEnabled(true);
```

Here item is your edittext or button or anything else

Try this:

```
if (room.getRoom_status().equals("0") &&room.getRoomType().getRoom_type_name().equals("0")) {
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.single);
               view.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (room.getRoom_status().equals("1") && room.getRoomType().getRoom_type_name().equals("0")) {
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.single_b);
            } else if (room.getRoom_status().equals("1") && room.getRoomType().getRoom_type_name().equals("1")) {
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.double_b);
            } else if(room.getRoom_status().equals("0") && room.getRoomType().getRoom_type_name().equals("1")){
                view.setEnabled(false);
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.doubleg);
            }
            else
            view.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: it should work when you make anything disabled it becomes non responsive to touch and click events. There must be something wrong in doing that.Can you please explain little bit what exactly do you want to disable ?

Comment: Try disabling your convertView where you required in specific case convertView.setEnabled(false);

Comment: Apply proper if conditions on the case where you want that and then disable your convertview and again enable it on else if condition is not satisfied to make it enable again when it is required.

Comment: I hope you understand what i m trying to say. Please tell me on which condition you want to check it I mean on which parameter so I can write code for you.

Comment: I needed the room state to determine whether item is clicked.

Comment: You are a very friendly person, my English is not good, please forgive me.

Comment: if  room state is "0",the item can't be clicked ,and if room state is “1”，it can be clicked

Comment: its ok n.p I just want to help you I updated the answer check if it works.

Comment: if (room.getRoom_status().equals("0") &&room.getRoomType().getRoom_type_name().equals("0")) {
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.single);
               view.setClickable(false);

Comment: also in other conditions where you want to make it clickable please do add view.setEnabled(true);

Comment: OK, let me try.

Comment: This is the way you can do that just check your conditions properly it will work.

Comment: Best of luck buddy :)